# .htaccess regex redirect and replace

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Going to show my lack of regex knowledge here but seem to be having trouble with the following:

I need to redirect the following example structure of a url:

www.example.com/blog-title-here/**tags/this+is+a+long+tag+name**

www.example.com/**tag/this-is-a-long-tag-name**

I need to redirect to just **/tag** and replace any instance of **+** with a **-**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this recursive redirect rule as your very first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "(?:.*/)?(tag/[^ +]*)[ +]+([^ +]*[ +].*)$" $1-$2 [N,NC,DPI]
RewriteRule "(?:.*/)?(tag/[^ +]*)[ +]+([^ +]*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

This will redirect `http://localhost/blog-title-here/tag/this+is+a+long+tag+name` to `http://localhost/tag/this-is-a-long-tag-name`

Comment: This doesnt seem to effect the url in anyway when i put it into my .htacess file?

Comment: This is tested and working on my Apache. Make sure this rule is placed before other rules. What is the exact URL you used for testing this?